# Wi-Fi Repeater app for android

Tags: android, android-wifi

I want to make an android app by which android phone can be used as a Wi-Fi repeater.
If one phone is connected to a wi-fi, and other phones can use the same wifi network using hotspot without any direct connection to the wifi network.

Is there any google or android API's available for this kind of app.

Comment: mmm...I think that you can achieve this using bluetooth...so Bluetooth API

Answer (score 0):

To do it I'm pretty sure that is required 2 networks interface.

The first used to connect with the router, the second one used ah hotspot. I don't think that you can do it with a normal phone.